# how save response from flask to .zip

Tags: python, flask, request

I'm have server on flask

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def main():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return send_from_directory(directory='./', filename='data.zip')
```

I send the request with

```
import requests
r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:5002", data=data)
```

I'm get

> Response [200]

How can i save the **r** in *data.zip* on client?

Comment: if server sends .zip file then simply use byte more `f = open('data.zip, 'wb'`)` and `f.writen(r.content)`,  `f.close()`. If file is big then you can use `post(..., stream=True)` and use loop to save in chunks. See [streaming requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#streaming-requests)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `open()`, `read()` and `close()` with byte mode `wb`

```
import requests

r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:5002", data=data)

f = open('data.zip', 'wb')
f.write(r.content)
f.close()
```

Or using `with`

```
import requests

r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:5002", data=data)

with open('data.zip', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

---

If it is bigger file then you can `stream` data to read and save in `chunks`

```
import requests

r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:5002", data=data, stream=True)

with open('data.zip', 'wb') as f:
     for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=8192): 
         f.write(chunk)
```

Requests doc: [Streaming Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#streaming-requests)

---

**BTW:** similar question on Stackoverflow: [Download large file in python with requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694907/download-large-file-in-python-with-requests)